# Why the join with the subquery isn't returning and matching all the values?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my code.

```
select trunc(q1.ex_date) as ex_date, 
count(*),
q2.total_cnt
from main_table q1
left join (select 
       trunc(ex_date) as ex_date, 
        count(*) total_cnt
        from main_table
        group by trunc(ex_date)) q2 on q2.ex_date =trunc(q1.ex_date)
group by trunc(q1.ex_date);
```

Currently, it's producing the following results:

```
EX_DATE             COUNT(*) TOTAL_CNT
09-NOV-20 00:00:00  681      207
10-NOV-20 00:00:00  739      207
11-NOV-20 00:00:00  449      207
12-NOV-20 00:00:00  762      207
13-NOV-20 00:00:00  566      207
14-NOV-20 00:00:00  207      207
15-NOV-20 00:00:00  207      207
```

The total_cnt column is repeating the same value.
It should be joining with the result from the subquery as follows:

```
15-NOV-20 00:00:00  207
16-NOV-20 00:00:00  458
09-NOV-20 00:00:00  681
10-NOV-20 00:00:00  739
12-NOV-20 00:00:00  762
11-NOV-20 00:00:00  449
13-NOV-20 00:00:00  566
14-NOV-20 00:00:00  207
```

Does anyone know why the join isn't giving me the total_cnt from the subquery

Comment: Please explain the results you want.  There may be better ways to get your desired results.

Comment: This is the abridged sql. My code has another group by condition that breaks the count(*) into 3 categories. For each of those categories within each date, I want to calculate the percentage for that given date and hence I needed the total_cnt. But this simple join isn't pairing the results for me.

Comment: I don't understand what result you are actually after. In your example the subquery returns the exact same count as the main query, so this makes no sense and gives us no hint. You may be looking for conditional aggregation.

Comment: @JohnAl Hope there's no need to reinvent the wheel. Oracle did that for you, [please check](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions124.htm): `ratio_to_report(1) over(partition by category)`. Because `count(*) = sum(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't get any result as the query you have written is invalid. You have an aggregate query but you are not aggregating or grouping on `q2.total_cnt` even though you are selecting it.

There were some bugs in older versions of Oracle (mainly 12.1 alongside the lateral view transformation) where it would ignore this, transform the query into something it can execute and give you a result.

Your query probably should look like

```
select trunc(q1.ex_date) as ex_date, 
count(*),
q2.total_cnt
from main_table q1
left join (select 
       trunc(ex_date) as ex_date, 
        count(*) total_cnt
        from main_table
        group by trunc(ex_date)) q2 on q2.ex_date =trunc(q1.ex_date)
group by trunc(q1.ex_date)
,q2.total_cnt;
```

Comment: Also accessing columns without alias can produce unexpected results, because the column may come not from table in subquery, but from main table and produce lateral join instead general join. Or am I wrong and Oracle is always so smart to avoid this?